# Android: Java.io.IOException: RST when requesting GCM token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, ioexception

I have been using GCM for long and it all went well, till now, when it throws

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: RST
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzl.zzb(Unknown Source:583)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzl.zza(Unknown Source:14)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzb(Unknown Source:60)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source:129)
W/System.err:     at com.snap.android.apis.model.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsHelper.requestToken(PushNotificationsHelper.kt:60)
```

My code is:

```
val instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context)
token = instanceID.getToken(context.getString(R.string.gcmSenderId),
            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)
```

Obviously, **not** from main thread.
The `exception.detailMessage` is `RST`.

Happens on OnePlus3 with Oreo on.
Building for SDK 25 (because we still haven't completed all the arrangements for Oreo).

We also have Firebase and it works splendid.

Anybody knows what's going on there?

Thanks